# Angular-mdc returning "No mixin named mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color"

Tags: angular, scss-mixins, mdc-components

So, I'm using angularCLI and angular-MDC, I want to use the second color of my `styles.scss`. There is on site https://trimox.github.io/angular-mdc-web/#/angular-mdc-web/top-app-bar-demo/sass this syntax `mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color($color)` I used and returns `No mixin named mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color`, below is my code:

#### component.html

```
<mdc-top-app-bar class="header-mdc" [mdcElevation]="5">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>Autonomous</h1>
  </div>
</mdc-top-app-bar>
```

#### component.scss

```
.header-mdc {
  @include mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color($mdc-theme-secondary);
}
```

#### styles.scss

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #6200ee; // primary color
$mdc-theme-secondary: #FFFFFF; // secondary color

@import '~@angular-mdc/theme/material';

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Thin';
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
}
```

#### ERROR

```
@include mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color($mdc-theme-secondary);
          ^
      No mixin named mdc-top-app-bar-fill-color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `@import '~@angular-mdc/theme/material';` at the top of your `component.scss` file it should work.

This feels a little improper though and I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: That's worked @Nathan after a long time that I don't see this project but today I tried so thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Thinking about this more, I'm wondering if the best way to do it would be to import `'~@angular-mdc/theme/material'` in a "top level" scss file and then `@import` that top level file into your components as needed. My worry is that the suggestion above may result in the full material scss being loaded for each component.